# shell script to monitor current errors in logfile

Tags: awk, grep, date

This script monitors logfile for pattern "ora",pull error details and send email.In this case i want to pull only the last error which come in logfile.
I set crontab for every 5 minutes,so grep pull out the same old errors which cause false alerts.The script should get errors with current time and should avoid looking for the old error.

```
mailto=xyz.email.com
logdirectory=/location/to/logfile
cd $logdirectory
grep "ORA" logfile
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
mailx -s "errors" $mailto
fi
```

My Logfile:

```
Fri Jun 07 05:09:32 2019 Archived Log entry 93 added for thread 1 sequence 59 ID 0xf10d426f dest 1: 
Fri Jun 07 11:08:20 2019 07-JUN-19 ORA-1100: Testing, Please Ignore
```

Comment: Your options are: 1) save a snapshot of your log file every time your cron job runs and do your grep on the diff between the previous snapshot and the current logfile, or 2) save the number of lines in your log file every time your cron job runs and then only do your grep (or more likely awk) on the number of lines past that line number or 3) save the grep output every time your cron job runs and and do a diff between the previous and current grep output and only report the differences. Option 2 would use the least disk space so I'd probably go with that.

Comment: Can you show me an example of option 2 command

Comment: Done. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/524676/133219

Comment: In general, this is not a good practice to work on a “live” log. If there is a must, OK, but consider using log rotate, even every minute, and parse the rotated files

Answer (score 0):

Showing option 2 from [my comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/523691/shell-script-to-monitor-current-errors-in-logfile?noredirect=1#comment968714_523691) as [requested by OP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/523691/shell-script-to-monitor-current-errors-in-logfile?noredirect=1#comment970368_523691):

```
awk -v parseLog='/some/where/filename' '
    BEGIN {
        prevNR=( (getline line < parseLog) > 0 ? line : 0 )
    }
    (NR>prevNR) && /ORA/{ print; found=1 }
    END {
        print NR > parseLog
        exit !found
    }
' /location/to/logfile
```

or in shell:

```
parseLog='/some/where/filename'
IFS= read -r line < "$parseLog"
if [[ -n "$line" ]]; then
    prevNR="$line"
else
    prevNR=0
fi
nr=$(wc -l < /tmp/logfile)
head -"$nr" /location/to/logfile |
    tail +"$(( "$prevNR" + 1 ))" |
    grep ORS
rslt=$?
printf '%d\n' "$nr" > "$parseLog"
```

Note that you need to get the number of lines with `wc` first, do a `head` for that number of lines and pipe THAT to tail and then to grep otherwise the log file might grow between the `grep` and the `wc` and then you'd miss a line on your next iteration or if you swapped the order of those then you could parse the same line twice.

Note that the above assume that whatever is writing to the log file does so in 1 atomic operation per line - if it's writing parts of lines separately and then attaching a newline when done then you need to ignore the last, possibly partial, line of the log file for the above parsing.